# How to add a margin between title and the price tag on mobile

Tags: html, css

I want to add a margin (a break `<br>`) between the title and the price tag on mobile. the website is http://www.jokerleb.com. I tried

```
.h3{
margin:5px;
}
// and

.tags{
margin:5px;
}
```

and I also tried working on other divs and media queries, nothing worked, it seems that just applying a margin won't change anything. I've been working on this super silly problem for 2 days and don't know why it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your html instead of images, we can't edit images!

Comment: @DarrenSweeney sure just 5 min

Comment: @Lynob Fixed the issue. Kindly check.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It's not worth adding any code here dude, the HTML and CSS are messed up. Remember, we are humans, we have exceptions.

Comment: if I put margin-bottom on the .tags {} then it works just fine. 
So make a media query, add the .tags { }  to it and add some margin bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it in a wrong way! It's crazily floated and stuff. You might need to do this and it would work:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .post-block .post-right h3 {
    max-width: 100%;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: I just added some margin bottom to the .tags { } and it works fine. I know the code is a mess but fixing it wouldn't need that much code. I think adding .tags { margin-bottom:Xpx; } to your media query would be enough (add a number on X). Beside that I should always work from top to bottom. So that's why adding margin-bottom.

Comment: @JeroenE I did that, and got some unintended effect.

Comment: man you're crazy fast, i cant even accept your answer yet, hell i didn't even finish writing the question yet, wow, thank you so much

Comment: could you take another look at the website please, i had to remove a class that was causing troubles on the website desktop version and now i have the same problem again

Comment: @Lynob Sure... What happened?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I had to remove a class i think it was called `.post-left{position: relative;}` it was adding too much margin on desktop version and now the tags are messed up again

Answer (score 3):

Just add `media query` like following to get the issue fix.

```
  @media (max-width:400px) {
       .tags {
        margin-bottom: 8px; /* Added */
        padding: 0;
        float: right;
        right: 24px;
        bottom: -12px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'd think this one is the best option. Only because what I just said: work from top to bottom (so using margin-bottom is the best practice). Beside that this is only one extra line for such small fix. Thanks LKG for working it out.

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Comment: I am not sure, may be I am wrong, but this looks like a hack job... `:S`

Comment: What kind of hack job @PraveenKumar ? it's a basic `media query`.

Comment: @LKG No buddy, you have my upvote. Something's not right with this method. Not sure why, as I did the same thing and I had issues.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, I upvoted the answer too but I have to go with the answer one since it fixed it immediately